Remove minutes value that is not divisible by 15 in Material Ui TimePicker component
I want to remove minutes value that is not divisible by 15 in Material Ui TimePicker component.
I am trying this approach but this is not working
const shouldDisableTime = (timeValue) => {
    const minutes = timeValue?.$m;
    return minutes !== 0 && minutes !== 15 && minutes !== 30 && minutes !== 45;
};

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <TimePicker
    value={time}
    onChange={(newValue) => setTime(newValue)}
    minutesStep={15}
    shouldDisableTime={shouldDisableTime}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>



"... but this is not working" Can you explain in detail what is not working? What debugging have you already done to try to figure this out yourself?

You can see in the photo that in the minutes field, 5, 10, 20, 25 are disabled. I need to remove the disabled value from the timepicker component. The user should only see 00, 15, 30 and 45.
Is this possibile to do?

Ah, so you only want the 00/15/30/45 minute values to be visible.

Yes, is this possible?

Instead of disabling time with shouldDisableTime() function you can use minutesStep={15} prop and for hiding not necessary minutes you can use skipDisabled boolean property with setting value to true.
Full <TimePicker /> component API can be found here.
See example screenshot bellow.


Please don't include code as an image. Even better would be the code and a link to a working example!
